# Switching between multiple windows

Tags: c#, console-application

I know there's quite a few similar questions to this but so far none of the answer have helped my problem. 
I have a process that contains multiple windows that display data, they are all meant to be display on a TV (similar to a dashboard). I'm trying to switch between all of them. I display the window for a minute and then switch to the next one. The code I'm using works for 3 windows Max, but when i try adding more windows it won't switch through all of them but only through the first 3.

All of the windows I'm trying to switch are under the same process. the process "dashboard10" contains all of the windows. The code all it does is press alt tab and then sleeps. I would appreciate if anyone knows of a different approach to accomplish this. Thank you

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("dashboard10");

            foreach (Process proc in processes)
            {
                try
                {
                    SetForegroundWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle);
                    SendKeys.SendWait("^" + "{TAB 2}");
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
            }

            Thread.Sleep(60000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are no windows at all in this code, just a loop that sends Ctrl+TABs to other processes. Using 10 processes instead of 10 windows is rather wasteful. In any case, are you sure the `processes` array contains more than 3 items? Or that the Ctrl+Tabs show what you expect them to show? Perhaps some of those processes have different names.

Comment: That loop goes through *all* processes and then waits for 2 minutes. Only the last process in the list will remain in the foreground. In case of delays the wrong application will receive the keystrokes

Comment: @Panagiotis I should've shared some photos, my apologies. The windows I'm referring to are from an application i built on Labview and it's an executable that shows multiple windows with data in it.

Comment: So basically when i click on the executable "dashboard10" it creates a process that can be seeing in the task manager called "dashboard10" and display 5 windows (they are called front panels on Labview). I'm trying to loop through all of those, I could potentially built those windows or front panels separately and have different processes names for it. I'm not sure if the outcome would be any different though. Anyway, I hope I made it a little more clear now.

Comment: @John Thanks for the editing :)